# Rollmean based on conditions

Tags: r, zoo

Based on the dataframe below, I would like to create a new column using rollmean based on three conditions - the values in column b match each other, the minimum values to be averaged in column a is 2, and I only want to average all values below the current row. If the amount of values to average is 2 or less, I would like to return a blank value.

I'm assuming that I will have to use an apply function to do this, but I'm not sure where to start.

```
a=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
b=c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z","Z")
df=as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

I would like the final table to look like:

```
Name    Value   Output
X        1         2.5
X        2         3
X        3  
X        4  
Y        1         2.5
Y        2         3
Y        3  
Y        4  
Z        1         2.5
Z        2         3
Z        3  
Z        4
```

Comment: Could you explain your condition with an example above? For example, how in above dataframe value 2.5 came at 1st row or why is it blank at 3rd row?

Comment: The output value in row 1 is the average of all of the following rows with name =X ,which is the average of 1,2,3,4. In row 2, the output is the average of 2,3,4 or 3. In the third row, there is not a sufficient number of values to average (less than 3), so the output returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `tidverse` solution. Within each group, if there is more than two items left, take the mean from the current index (`row_number()`) up to the final index (`n()`).

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  mutate(Output = map_dbl(row_number(), ~ifelse(n() - . < 3, NA, mean(a[.:n()]))))
```

#### Data

The way you create your data coerces `b` into a character vector (because `cbind` makes a matrix).

Use simply:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
b <- c("X","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z","Z","Z")
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

Or

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4, b = rep(c('X', 'Y', 'Z'), each = 4))
```

Comment: If I wanted to apply this same idea to a larger data set, and take the rolling mean of 500 items with a new minimum of 150, then I know I can change the < 3 to <150, but how could I change the above equation to only  take the mean of the following 500 items as opposed to all remaining items? Hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Either `~ifelse(n() - . < 150, NA, mean(a[.:(. + 500)], na.rm = TRUE))` or `~ifelse(n() - . < 150, NA, mean(a[.:min(. + 500, n())]))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is an error in the formation of `df` in the question so we have modified it below.  We can use `ave` like this. No packages are used.

```
df <- data.frame(a, b)
fun <- function(x) if (length(x) <= 2) NA else rev(cumsum(rev(x)) / c(NA, NA, 3:length(x)))
transform(df, Output = ave(a, b, FUN = fun))
```

giving:

```
   a b Output
1  1 X    2.5
2  2 X    3.0
3  3 X     NA
4  4 X     NA
5  1 Y    2.5
6  2 Y    3.0
7  3 Y     NA
8  4 Y     NA
9  1 Z    2.5
10 2 Z    3.0
11 3 Z     NA
12 4 Z     NA
```